# DynamoDB - Get is not working

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using a library called dynamoose to access dynamoDB.

https://github.com/automategreen/dynamoose

I have defined a model:

```
var App = dynamoose.model('AppTest', new dynamoose.Schema ({
   appID: { type: String, hashkey: true },
   email: String,
   isMaster: Boolean,
   password: String
}));
```

When I do a save operation, everything works fine and data is saved to db.

```
    var app = new App({ 
       appID: user.appID, 
       email: user.email,     
       isMaster: false, 
       password: user.pwd 
    });

    app.save(function (err) {
       // Data is saved, and no error here
    });
```

Then when I try to get the data I saved, there's also no error, but user is undefined, although it exists in the db:

```
    App.get({ email: 'some_existing_email' }, function (err, user) {
       // err = null, user = undefined

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is around how you access a record in DynamoDB.

‘get’ can only be used on the main table key. In this case appID.

```
App.get({appID: 'abc'})
```

For you case, since emails just a normal field, you would have to use ‘scan’.

```
App.scan('email').eq('user@example.com').exec()
```

If you defined email as a the range key, you could use ‘get’ with the appID and email

```
var App = dynamoose.model('AppTest', new dynamoose.Schema ({
   appID: { type: String, hashkey: true },
   email: { type: String, rangeKey: true },
   isMaster: Boolean,
   password: String
}));

App.get({appID: 'abc', email: 'user@example.com'})
```

If email was defined as a global index, you could use ‘query’.

```
var App = dynamoose.model('AppTest', new dynamoose.Schema ({
   appID: { type: String, hashkey: true },
   email: { type: String, index: { global: true }},
   isMaster: Boolean,
   password: String
}));

App.query('email').eq('user@example.com').exec()
```

As a note, both query and scan return arrays.

Answer (score 0):

In DynamoDB you get items by its primary key. In your example, the primary key is `appId`. You are attempting to get the data using the email address. You need to change this getting the item using the `appId`.

If you need to get items by `email` then you should create a secondary index which uses email address as the hash key. Then you can fetch data by email address by querying the secondary index.